# Unexpected section header '\examples' when checking R package

Tags: r, package

When I use R CMD check pkg_name to check my own R package, I obtain warnings like this:

```
unexpected section header '\examples'
unexpected section header '\keyword'
```

The problem exists in the .Rd file where I write some example R codes for my own data (i.e. the .Rd file is for a .RDdata file, not for an .R function file). I was thinking that we can just write example codes ("...") between the `{}` below:

```
\example{
...
}
```

Unfortunately it cannot pass the package checking procedure...Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see the `.Rd` file in question....

Comment: I've experienced this issue before - the problem was that I forgot to close a `{}` bracket pair earlier on in the .Rd file. Maybe try checking for that?

Comment: @AriB.Friedman: thanks for the reply! I found the issue in my .Rd file.

Comment: @Edward: Yes, there is indeed a mismatch of {} found in the .Rd file. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @alittleboy Have you considered using roxygen2 to create your help files?

Comment: If you fixed the issue, could you answer your own question (so that others can learn from the example and the question will be removed from the unanswered questions feed?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a mismatch of { } in the .Rd file that causes the issue. It is very hard to detect,Make sure you have matched pairs before doing R CMD check pkg_name.

Answer (score 43):

I once experienced this problem when using the percentage symbol (`%`). I was trying to write documentation for a confidence interval parameter.  I then realised that I needed to escape the symbol with a backslash to resolve the error (just like in LaTeX). Thus, I replaced `%` with `\%`. This fixed the error.

Answer (score 3):

This error message may get more hits now that roxygen2 (mercifully) [supports markdown](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/markdown.html).  If converting from an old LaTeX-style file, some LaTeX-legal syntax may still by hiding from manual conversion.

Converting from `word' to 'word' resolved my Rd parsing error (*i.e.*, changed the leading backtick to a conventional quote).

Comment: I had it because i used the backticks and forgot to add`Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)` to the description file